# Prove this trigonometric identity $\frac{1 - \cosθ}{\sinθ} = \frac{\sinθ}{1 + \cosθ}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1 - \cosθ}{\sinθ} = \frac{\sinθ}{1 + \cosθ}$$

using $$\sin^2θ + \cos^2θ = 1$$

any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's the same as $(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)=(\sin\theta)(\sin\theta)$.

Comment: $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$. Now factor the RHS.

Comment: Isn't the answer shouting at you "Hey, can't you see me"? :)

Comment: Did you even try to reduce to a common denominator ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't think that they are the same. For the one you have written, $\theta = 2\pi$ is a solution but the one in the question, it isn't unless there is a given interval for $\theta$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I spent hours on this, I was just approaching it the wrong way from the beginning each time. Instead of multiplying the LHS numerator and denominator by sin^2θ I was squaring the whole fraction to get the values into a higher power and manipulate from that point. Hence coming here in full knowledge I was making overcomplicating something very simple

Comment: @JayM: this is not what I suggested. Reduce to the same denominator. No trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta} &= \frac{(1-\cos \theta )\sin \theta}{(1+\cos \theta)(1-\cos \theta)} \\
&= \frac{(1-\cos \theta )\sin \theta}{1-\cos^2\theta} \\
&= \frac{(1-\cos \theta )\sin \theta}{\sin^2 \theta} \\
&= \frac{1-\cos \theta }{\sin \theta}
\end{align}$$
whenever $\theta \notin \{ k\pi :\, k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{\big(1-\cos(\theta)\big)\sin(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)} = \frac{\big(1-\cos(\theta)\big)\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos^2(\theta)} = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}$$

But as a small note, for instance $\theta = 2\pi$ does not satisfy that equality. So this is not true in general. I just posted this answer to show you how to manipulate one expression to get another.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

For non-zero $b,d$, one has
$$\frac ab=\frac cd\iff ad=bc.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1 - \cosθ}{\sinθ} = \frac{\sinθ}{1 + \cosθ}\iff
\frac{1 - \cos^2θ}{(1+\cos\theta)\sinθ} = \frac{\sin^2θ}{(1+\cos\theta)\sinθ}.$$